# How to insert category and subcategory using 'wp_insert_post' function?

Tags: categories, wp-insert-post

How would be the array, to insert a post category and subcategory?

Thanks.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: [You are expected to have researched the problem and made an attempt at solving it before posting a question.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) Whatever the truth may be, this question gives the impression that very little thought or research went into it. Even the automated "low-quality post" system flagged it.

Comment: Ok I´ll read the link

Answer (score 4):

The argument description in [the Codex entry for `wp_insert_post()` has exactly what you need (reformatted)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post).

```
'post_category'  => [ array(<category id>, <...>) ] 
//post_category no longer exists, try wp_set_post_terms() for setting a post's categories
```

So, per the Codex. Use [`wp_set_post_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_object_terms/).

```
wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, array( 1, 2, 3), 'category', true );
```

For custom taxonomies:

```
'tax_input' => array( 
  'taxonomy_name' => array( 
    'term', 
    'term2', 
    'term3' 
  ) 
); // support for custom taxonomies.
```

Just change the taxonomy name to the one you want and replace the `term` placeholders with the category slugs you want.

The Codex weakly implies that you can no longer set the category via `wp_insert_post()`. However, while I haven't tested it I would not be surprised if that `tax_input` argument also works for the `category` taxonomy, like so:

```
'tax_input' => array( 
  'category' => array( 
    'a', 
    'b', 
    'c' 
  ) 
);
```

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying that `post_category` in `wp_insert_post` does work, or does it not?

Comment: when you use post_category you just need to send an array of post category IDs to it.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me with [wp_set_object_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_object_terms/)